# Selecting the no of rows from the database using the year stored in date field

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Can any one help me get the total # of records from a database table, using year?

I have a table - in that I saved the exam date in a date field.  I need to get the total # of records from that table using the year only.

I am using mysql.

This is my table

```
|  e_id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| exam_name   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| exam_date   | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

I need to to get the total no of exam held in a particular year only

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at the MySQL Date functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want? Your question is a little vague though.
`SELECT COUNT(*) as 'total' FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%Y') = '2011'`

`table` is the name of your table, `date_field` is the field in your table where the date is stored, and then you can just replace 2011 with whatever year you are trying to search for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions, like `DATE_FORMAT()` in @Brian's answer, or the `YEAR()` function like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total 
FROM table 
WHERE YEAR(date_field) = 2011
```

However, this approach will not be fast if the table has more than a few thousands rows because it will have to fully scan the whole table and apply the function for all the records of the table . It's better, in any case, to have a condition like @Ruslan's (if it's a `DATETIME` field) or like this if it's a `DATE` field:

```
WHERE date_field BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
```

I prefer the condition that works for either (DATE or DATETIME) types:

```
WHERE date_field >= '2011-01-01' 
  AND date_field <  '2012-01-01'
```

---

If you have an index on the `date_field`, the query will use the index for the counting without scanning the full table and will be many times faster.

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL, you can do something like:

```
BETWEEN '2010-05-31 00:00:00' AND '2010-06-06 23:59:59'
```

And as you would like to query by year only, that would be:

```
BETWEEN '2005-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-11-31 23:59:59'
```

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: -1 because it's a longer way to select a year. On top of that a year has 12 months.

Comment: +1 because it will use the index of the date_field (if there is one) and will not scan the whole table.

Comment: @Eljakim: in SQL, sometimes longer query means faster.

Comment: @ypercube, you may be correct, BUT, he is looking at exams, so it's unlikely that there is a lot of data. On top of that the way Ruslan has done it makes it easier to make mistakes in your query. Even though his query appears to be correct the typo (2011-11-31) will not cause any SQL errors, yet it skips most of december! Personally with small datasets I would go for the `YEAR` function, and only on large datasets for something else.

Comment: The down vote was a misjudgment. 

We are all here trying to find the best way to perform a task in coding terms, and you did assume a small amount of data for his exams table which is incorrect. With time when the data will have tons of rows, the user WILL revert to use the date_time index as Eljakim hinted. Good luck.